# Why am I getting an ambiguous invocation error in Where?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a simple object that I'm creating a collection of.  From that collection I need to find duplicates that have the same TransitMapSegmentID.

```
public class LineString
{
    public int TransitLineID { get; set; }
    public string TransitLineName { get; set; }
    public int TransitMapSegmentID { get; set; }
    public string HexColor { get; set; }
    public double[][] Coordinates { get; set; }
}

var lineStrings = new List<LineString>();
```

With the code below I'm getting a "ambiguous invocation match" error from he lambda expression below.  Can anyone explain why?

```
var result = lineStrings
             .Where(a => lineStrings
             .Count(b => b.TransitMapSegmentID == a.TransitMapSegmentID) > 1);
```

Comment: I pasted your code into LinqPad and it worked perfectly fine -- no compiler error.

Comment: same. Try to clean your soluton and rebuild.

Comment: Even if there is no error, try to not write `.Where(a => .... .Where(b => a == b))` as it creates a cross product. Tim's solution is a much better way to find duplicates

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using? Also, are you referencing LINQ libraries from multiple .NET versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find all duplicate lines based on their `TransitMapSegmentID`, use [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx):

```
var result = lineStrings
            .GroupBy(ls => ls.TransitMapSegmentID)
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(grp => grp);
```

Comment: I've tried multiple versions like this but I get that same error no matter what GroupBy version I use.

Comment: Not sure why but it seems to be working now.  I think it may have been Resharper acting strange.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, but one last quick question.  Is there a way to add a Order by to that statement?

Comment: @NullReference: Of course, try for example `.OrderBy(ls => ls.TransitLineName);` (at the end)

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, is there a way to order by the Count?

Comment: @NullReference: add this before the `SelectMany`: `.OrderBy(grp => grp.Count())`. If you want to order descending(highest num of dups first), use `OrderByDescending` instead.